# jQuery works, but I'm looking for plain vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This site has been incredibly helpful, to the point that this is the first time I've needed to post a question. I'm stuck... I have a search form in html that has a onKeyUp event that triggers a div with results to appear.

```
<form id="searchform">
    <div>
        What are you looking for? <input tabindex="0" type="text" size="30" value="" id="inputString" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);"  />
        </div>
    <div id="suggestions"></div>
</form>
```

The body has a onLoad() event that puts a blur on the input box that closes search results when the input loses focus.

```
function searchbox() {

var elem;
    elem = document.getElementById('inputString');

elem.blur(function(){

    document.getElementById('suggestions').style.display = 'none';

 });
}
```

The issue that I run into is that this it doesn't close the div on blur... But if I use jQuery and replace the elem var with $("input"), it works just fine. I've tried many different things and I get one of two results. Either the div won't go away on the blur, which makes the links within the div active and clickable. Or, the blur event works and the div disappears, but it goes before the link can be clicked on and activated.

So my question is, what would the vanilla javascript be for the jQuery? My understanding is that it is assigning the blur event to all inputs.

```
$("input")
```

I know I could use it, and it does work, but I'm trying to learn without and trying to understand what jQuery does more than just plugging in stuff I find on the net. I hope I've left enough info for a little guidance.

Comment: Here's a JS Fiddle of it, http://jsfiddle.net/jar862/93th2/2/
I don't know why, but it won't work on there but it works in an actual page.

Comment: You need to set the load type for the javascript to 'No Wrap - in <body>' for this to work in JSFiddle. :) - Have you found the solution to your question yet?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
elem.onblur = function(){
    document.getElementById('suggestions').style.display = 'none';
};
```

jQuery's `.blur` is a shortcut for the `.on( "blur", handler )` and `blur` is an event, so you can attach to by assigning function to the property `onblur`.

Comment: This must have been one of the methods I tried. It allows the onblur to close the div, but it triggers before the link can be clicked. Thanks though.

Comment: Add timeout then: `elem.onblur = function () { setTimeout(function () { ... }, 100); };`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it has IE support too, but addEventListener is also supported by IE9+

```
function searchbox() {
   var elem = document.getElementById('inputString');
   if(window.addEventListener) {
     elem.addEventListener('blur', function(event) {
       document.getElementById('suggestions').style.display = 'none';
     }, false);
   } elseif(window.atatchEvent) {
     window.attachEvent("onblur", function(event) {
       document.getElementById('suggestions').style.display = 'none';
    });
   } else {
      alert("Your browser does not support events");
   }
}
```

Comment: Has the same affect as the previous suggestion, allows the div to close but it doesn't allow the links in that div to be able to be clicked. It's like a hierarchy where the blur trigger fires before the link has time to trigger.

Comment: Can you post a JS fiddle of what your problem entails? Well are you creating those elements dynamically?

Comment: RPM, heres the JSFiddle, but I can't get it to work at all in there. http://jsfiddle.net/jar862/93th2/1/

I just realized that I didn't add the link tag to the str when it should insert it into the div. Fixed that.